# Getting error about Controlls collection cannot be modified when using AJAXToolKit's calender extender

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add the CalenderExternder feature from the AJAXTool kit. When I add the control to my page, build, and debug I get the following error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
>
> Source Error: 
>    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace: 
>   [HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).]
>      System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) +9600379
>      AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control control) +702
>      AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +62
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Here is my entire code for the page, it works fine as long as I dont have the  tag in my code. i ahve the tool kit registered in my web.config file and the masterpage is useing the ToolkitScriptManager

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/AdminLayout.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManageReleaseInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="FFInfo.Staff.Sections.ManageReleaseInfo" %>
<asp:Content ID="phContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">
<h2 class="text-center">
    <asp:Literal ID="lblTitle" runat="server" />
</h2>

<asp:Label ID="lblResults" CssClass="text-error" runat="server" />

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsErrorSummary" CssClass="text-error" DisplayMode="BulletList" HeaderText="The following errors have been found:" runat="server" />

<p>
    What section is this for?
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSectionList" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Select Section Title" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />Release Title:
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbReleaseTitle" Columns="50" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReleaseTitleRequired" ControlToValidate="tbReleaseTitle" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="text-error" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please there the release title." runat="server" />

    <br />Platform:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPlatform" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Select Platform" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />Publisher:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPublisher" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Select Publisher" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />Release Location:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Select Locaiton" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />Estimated Release Date:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReleaseDate" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Select Estimated Date" />
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />Exact Release Date:
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbReleaseDate" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" />
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ceReleaseDate" TargetControlID="tbReleaseDate" runat="server" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ReleaseDateCheck" ControlToValidate="tbReleaseDate" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{1,2})[./-]+([0-9]{1,2})[./-]+([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in MM/DD/YYYY format please." runat="server" />
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the `</asp:Content>` tag in the code you have posted. Is this also missing in your actual code?

Comment: @DanielZiga No it is in my code, just missed it in the copy/paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going to get some dinner and coming back I started googleing this again and found a very realvent post at http://forums.asp.net/t/1172295.aspx/1

In testing I have bundled sytles on my master page that are causing the problem. I simply had to wrape the style.render tag, in my  tag, with a PlaceHolder tag. Once that was done everything is working great.

Comment: Funny enough, i had the similar problem this solution gave me clue to my issue. Long story short: I had to wrap my *other* content with <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"/>